# CORS: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check when add header

Tags: javascript, node.js, cors

My html of express client:

```html
<html>
<body>
    <h1>
        <%= title %>
    </h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %>
    </p>

    <script>
        function output(txt) {
            const pre = document.createElement('pre');

            pre.innerText = txt;
            document.body.append(pre);

            return pre;
        }
        
        (async function () {
            const headers = new Headers()
            // headers.append("Authorization",'Basic ' + btoa('root' + ':' + 'root'))
            const { a } = await fetch('http://localhost:3002/', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers:headers, 
                mode: 'cors', 
            }).then(r => r.json());
            output(`camera: ${a}`);
        })();
        
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

and i have made the following settings in `http://localhost:3002/`, i added `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization");
  res.end(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
});


module.exports = router;
```

it work, i will get `a` from `http://localhost:3002/`, and the response header has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.
[image]
but when i add this to fetch.headers: `headers.append("Authorization",'Basic ' + btoa('root' + ':' + 'root'))`

i will get this:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3002/' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

and preflight

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Allow: GET,HEAD
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 8
ETag: W/"8-ZRAf8oNBS3Bjb/SU2GYZCmbtmXg"
Date: Thu, 27 May 2021 06:27:19 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
```

and in chrome, has this view, `Provisional headers are shown`:
[image: Provisional headers are shown]

i don't know why, I have read many articles.
any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding CORS response headers to a `get` endpoint, but the error message says that the **preflight** request (which uses OPTIONS, not GET) is failing. You need to set up something along the lines of:

```
router.options('*', code_to_respond_with_suitable_headers);
```

That said:

Don't reinvent the wheel.

Do use the [cors module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors).

Do follow the modules instructions on how to [support options routes](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight).

Comment: I followed your suggestion and used it on my server side
```
var cors = require('cors')
router.options('*',cors(), function(req, res, next) {
   res.json({ a: 2 });
});
```
And it works!

Comment: But can I force it to use the GET method?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request — no.